# Pointfree function for fold left operation

Tags: haskell, fold, pointfree

I have this function that extracts the fourth element, which happens to be an integer, out of a tuple:

```
fourth :: (a, b, c, Int) -> Int
fourth (a, b, c, d) = d
```

I want to sum all the fourth integers of a list of tuples. I can use `fourth` inside a fold right operation by composing it with `(+)` into a suitable `foldr` operator:

```
summerRight :: (a, b, c, Int) -> Int -> Int
summerRight tuple n = fourth tuple + n
```

the whole thing can be written pointfree:

```
summerRight = (+) . fourth
```

Now, if I want to express the sum as a fold left, I need an operator:

```
summerLeft :: Int -> (a, b, c, Int) -> Int
summerLeft n tuple = n + fourth tuple
```

I cannot manage to write this last function pointfree.

Is it possible to write `summerLeft` pointfree?

If it's not, is there some possible reasoning that relates fold right with pointfree programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c` for this:

```
fourth :: (a, b, c, Int) -> Int
fourth (a, b, c, d) = d

summerLeft :: Int -> (a, b, c, Int) -> Int
summerLeft = flip ((+) . fourth)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ summerLeft 1 (2, 3, 4, 5)
```

prints

```
6
```

Comment: Mmmh, it reminds me of the thrush combinator Txy = yx. Looks like a general approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
summerLeft n tuple = n + fourth tuple
summerLeft n = (n +) . fourth
summerLeft = (. fourth) . (+)
```